# How to run raw SQL Query with Zend Framework 2

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

Is there a way to execute a SQL String as a query in Zend Framework 2?

I have a string like that:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE myColumn = 5"
```

now I want to execute this string directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;

$dbAdapterConfig = array(
    'driver'   => 'Mysqli',
    'database' => 'dbname',
    'username' => 'dbusername',
    'password' => 'dbuserpassword'
);
$dbAdapter = new Adapter($dbAdapterConfig);

$sql = new Sql($dbAdapter);
$select = $sql->select();
$select->from('testTable');
$select->where(array('myColumn' => 5));

$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$result = $statement->execute();
```

S. docu: [Zend\Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/index.html#zend-db) → [Zend\Db\Sql](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html)

Comment: I am using this approach to execute some complex queries directly in a controller and it works fine, but the problem is that I need to declare the adapter in every action where I need it, which is redundant. I would like to create the adapter only once and then call it in the actions where I need it, but I haven´t figured out how to do it... so my question is, How and where should you declare or create the dbAdapter in a way that later on you can just call it in different actions in a controller, without having to declare it everytime you need to execute a different query?

Comment: @Clarissa You should never execute SQL in a controller. It breaks the MVC priciple. The Communication with the database is the job of the model.

Comment: @Automatix I know... but I am recently starting to use Zend framework and I have had a hard time to making it work properly with this case. In most of my application I am using the correct MVC principle, where all the data access happens in the model. I know the controllers are supposed to be thin, but in this particular case, I need to execute 2 complex queries that include 5 tables and one stored procedure each. I didn't know how to process according to the standard, and this was the way that seemed to work, even when it is not the proper one... that´s why i am still trying to fix it.

Comment: This is not raw SQL query launch. You did not answer the question.

Comment: @Clarissa (or anybody reading this) To keep data-fetching queries out of your controllers, simply have the controller call a function in the model that builds and executes the query, even if it means making multiple functions in the model that are called by the initial function.

Answer (score 55):

Just pass the sql string to your db adapter like this:

```
$resultSet = $adapter->query($sql, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

And if you want to pass parameters:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE myColumn = ?";
$resultSet = $adapter->query($sql, array(5));
```

EDIT: Please note that the query method does not always returns a resultset. When its a resultset producing query(`SELECT`) it returns a `\Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet` otherwise(`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, ...) it will return a `\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ResultInterface`.

And when you leave the second Parameter empty you will get a `\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\StatementInterface` which you can execute.

Comment: @Clarissa Which link? Please share.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using tableGateway, you can run your raw SQL query using this statement,

```
$this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->driver->getConnection()->execute($sql);
```

where $sql pertains to your raw query. This can be useful for queries that do not have native ZF2 counterpart like TRUNCATE / INSERT SELECT statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `EntityManager` $em on your hands, you can do something like this:

```
   $select = $em->getConnection()->executeQuery("
        SELECT a.id, a.title, a.announcement, asvc.service_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
            GROUP_CONCAT(asvc.service_id SEPARATOR \", \") AS svc_ids
        FROM article AS a
        JOIN articles_services AS asvc ON asvc.article_id = a.id
        WHERE
        asvc.service_id IN (
            SELECT tsvc.service_id
            FROM tender AS t
            JOIN tenders_services AS tsvc ON tsvc.tender_id = t.id
            WHERE t.id = :tenderId
        )
        GROUP BY a.id
        ORDER BY cnt DESC, a.id DESC
        LIMIT :articlesCount
    ", [
        'articlesCount' => 5,
        'tenderId' => $tenderId,
    ], [
        'articlesCount' => \PDO::PARAM_INT,
    ]);

    $result = $select->fetchAll(); // <-- here are array of wanted rows
```

I think this way to execute complex queries is best for Zend. But may be I'm not very smart in Zend still. Will glad to see if it helps to someone.