# How to select a schema in a multi-schema database with ZF2 DB adapter?

Tags: sql, zend-framework2

I have a MSSQL database which implements multiple schemas. If I was to write SQL manually, I would do: `SELECT * FROM [myschema].[mytable]`.

However I'm trying to use ZF2 DB tools.

```
$sql = new Sql($dbAdapter);
$select = $sql->select($my_table_name)
        ->columns(array('*'));

...
$sqlQuery = $select->getSqlString($dbAdapter->getPlatform());
error_log($sqlQuery);
$statement = $dbAdapter->query($sqlQuery);
$result = $statement->execute();
```

If I set the `$my_table_name = 'mytable'` the adapter escapes it so: `...FROM [mytable]`.

If I set it to `$my_table_name = 'myschema.mytable'` I get `...FROM [myschema.mytable]`.

What I want is `...FROM [myschema].[mytable]` but I can't seem to get that. I don't see an option to set the database schema in the docs.

Apart from manually creating the SQL, how would you address this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332671/how-to-run-raw-sql-query-with-zend-framework-2

check the 2nd answer thats prob what you are looking for.

Comment: No, as stated in my question I don't want to execute a raw SQL, I'm trying to find out how build it programmatically, for the purpose of escaping and to be able to use it with different DB adapters.

Comment: Setup multiple database adapter like in link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003187/configure-multiple-databases-in-zf2.  Then use db adapter as per choice.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't show how to select a schema either. I'm getting the feeling that ZF doesn't know what DB schema/namespace is :( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Hi @David, I'm afraid I moved away from PHP a while ago now. I don't recall what I ended up doing - but leaving the question here for reference! Sorry for not being of more help!