# Using ZF2, create a WITH statement?

Tags: sql-server, zend-framework2, with-statement

How do I create this SQL using ZF2?

```
WITH    q AS 
        (
        SELECT  m.*, CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY m.PersonId) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN AS bc
        FROM    mytable m
        WHERE   ParentID IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  m.*,  q.bc + '.' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.ParentID ORDER BY m.PersonID) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
        FROM    mytable m
        JOIN    q
        ON      m.parentID = q.PersonID
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
ORDER BY
        bc
```

<sub>From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1757302/351785</sub>

Starting in a model, I can do the last bit:

```
$this->tableGateway->select()->orderBy('bc');
```

It's the `WITH` section I need help with.

Comment: Maybe you should send it as "raw query", see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332671/how-to-run-raw-sql-query-with-zend-framework-2

Comment: I may have to go that way - however I was hoping there was a built-in set of classes/functions I could use - especially as I will be using this a few times in my application =/

Comment: You are free to create a class/function by yourself (maybe as a module) and use this ;)

Comment: That will be the approach I take.